# Can students transfer to a new high school purely on their will?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, new-york-city, school, students

My high school life was subpar at the very least. I was constantly bullied and never received the necessary protection from school staff. This coupled with dwindling grades created a negative feedback loop. My health was degrading both mentally and physically so I consulted the school counselor. She was unwilling to provide any help let alone documents needed for a transfer. My custodial parent wasn't any more supportive either, so I gave up on the idea and kept going to school, barely meeting the requirements for graduation.

It's been almost two decades since I graduated and left NYC, but bad memories still haunt me to this day. From time to time I wonder whether I might have been able to switch schools without the school's nor my custodial parent's consent, had I known better.

Can students struggling like me submit transfer applications on their own to move to another school unsponsored? Does the availability of such choices vary by state?

Comment: Note that this site [How to Transfer High Schools: A Complete Guide](https://blog.prepscholar.com/how-to-transfer-high-schools) says "If you are younger than 18 years old, you will need your parent/guardian to submit your transfer request." I don't think you would need your school's *consent*, otherwise they could restrict your (and guardian's) freedom of choice. And consider if you are relocating – the school would not be able to insist you remain at their school. But it also says you will need "transcripts from your current high school" so you would still need the school's cooperation.

Comment: "Does the availability of such choices vary by state?" Yes. Education is primarily a state and local function in the U.S.

Comment: I think in NYC the schools are operated by the municipal government, and the same holds in some other states. But in Minnesota schools are run by independent school districts, whose board members are elected by voters within the school district, and that have their own power of taxation. So pretty much everything about the way school systems are organized varies quite a lot from one state to another.

Answer (score 3):

The primary question is whether the target school can/must accept you. A private school is not compelled to accept you, a public school might be. Because of the law compelling you (as a minor) to go to school, some public school will have to accept you as a student. However, as a minor, your preference is low on the list of legal priorities. The primary controlling factor is the school district where you live, and their policy. They may demand that you attend the school "in the area where you live", or it can be an urging of various strengths. It is conceivable that you can attend school in an entirely different district (we have some cross-district migration possibilities, but that is rare).

If district policy allows for a student to go to a school outside their home zone, then the question of discretion comes up: it is highly unlikely that a district would allow a problem student to "impose" himself on a foreign school, so the school intended to receive the student probably has some say in the matter. Parental consent will be essential, so if the parent(s) oppose moving the student, the district is unlikely to allow the transfer. The student might also be consulted. In other words, no, student desire alone will not enable the student to transfer schools. The school that you are assigned to by default has even less direct say in the matter, but indirectly it could influence the recipient school's willingness to allow the transfer.

For NYC, [here](https://www.schools.nyc.gov/enrollment/enrollment-help/transfers) is a preliminary page regarding transfers. Safety and accessibility concerns are easy, also moving within the city etc. but academic and social concerns are "a possibility", one to be determined on a case by case basis.